Scrolling lag on Ubuntu
I have 2-3 seconds lags while scrolling pages on web browsers. I tried all the browsers available and it happens on all of them. I keep installing all the updates and this problem persists since months maybe a year.
Specs of my laptop:
i3-5005U CPU, 8 gb RAM, 120 gb SSD drive (97% health) and Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2).
OS version: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Gnome: 42.9
Wayland

Your CPU is fairly old, nearly nine years and was at the time is was released not the most powerfull CPU. Browsers are today very demanding with regards to CPU power, as they can do and have to do a lot of things.
It is just a guess, but I'd say your problem is not software releated but hardware related.

Switched to X11. Maybe it's faster.
